# Change button property depending of UITextField length

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Im try to change my button state depending of length of text, user put in textfield. I don't know why following logic not work:

```
-(IBAction)doneButtonFired:(id)sender{

    if ([self.myTextField.text length] > 0){
    self.doneButton.enabled = YES;
        NSLog(@"YES");
    [self.delegate stringChangedTo:self.myTextField.text atIndex:self.indexToPass];
    [self.delegate completeTask:[self getTimeDifference:self.oldDate]];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }   else if ([self.myTextField.text length] < 1){
        NSLog(@"NOO");
        self.doneButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Thats not work too (because it check old value):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ([self.myTextField.text length] > 0){
        NSLog(@" > 0");
    }   else if ([self.myTextField.text length] == 0){
        NSLog(@" < 0");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

How to fix that simple problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing something like:

```
[self.myTextField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

in you viewDidLoad then:

```
-(void) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if([textField.text length]>0){
      self.doneButton.enabled = YES;
  }else{
      self.doneButton.enabled = NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: where can i get complete list of UIControl events?

Comment: In interface builder drag out any element that is a subclass of uicontrol and right click.